# How to show records which were created within 10mins apart

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How do i return records which were created on the same day within 10mins? I would like to show all items with a created date `smalldatetime`.

I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT NAME,
       TITLE,
       CREATED
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  CREATEDBY = 'Billy'
GROUP  BY NAME,
          TITLE,
          CREATED,
          Datepart(YEAR, CREATED),
          Datepart(MONTH, CREATED),
          Datepart(DAY, CREATED),
          Datepart(HOUR, CREATED),
          ( Datepart(MINUTE, CREATED) / 10 )
```

Comment: Please add the schema

Comment: Is CREATED field a date or char datatype?

Comment: created is `SMALLDATETIME`

Comment: Then you have written "WHERE  CREATED = 'Billy'". What's Billy?

Comment: sorry it should be called, `CreatedBy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding. Try below code:

```
SELECT NAME,
       TITLE,
       CREATED
FROM   TABLE
WHERE CreatedBy  = 'Billy'  
AND CREATED BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE,-10,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE();
```

Comment: `'MIN' is not a recognized dateadd option.`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton: So, based on your having accepted this answer, your actual question was "How to show records which were created within *the last* 10mins?", correct?